# Applications of Modular Representation Theory

Tags: representation-theory

Apologize if this is a newbie question.

Modular Representation Theory is the study of $k[G]$-modules where $k$ is a field, $G$ is a finite group, such that $p=\mathrm{char}\ k$ divides $|G|$.

Besides studying for its own sake, what are the applications? Why people care? Any good references devoted to *applications*?

[The Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_representation_theory) stated it is used in (for example) algebraic geometry and number theory, but no more details (or even hints).
(It seems to me) the mathematical content of the article is about the theory itself, so does the references therein.

Did a bit of googling. Only application I found is a section of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{F}_p)$ in [Tony Feng’s notes (based on Daniel Bump’s course)](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Efengt/mod_rep_theory.pdf), where MRT is used to construct complex representations.

I am aware of [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194342/what-is-modular-representation-theory-for-groups-good-for), but its answers seem to be mainly aim at people with more background.

Comment: There’s the fact that it’s an obvious extension of the theory over $\mathbb{C}$. Namely, one is tempted to ask what is the analog of the theory in characteristic $p$. I remember it being necessary to prove the Euler-Poincaré characteristic formula over local fields: more precisely, given a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and $M$ a finite $G_K$ module, can we say anything about the quotient $|H^0(G_K,M)||H^2(G_K,M)|/|H^1(G_K,M)|$? It turns out that yes: I don’t remember the argument, but I remember that modular representation theory was really necessary when $pM=0$.

Comment: Possibly dumb follow-up: why one cares about the quotient of $|H^0|\cdot|H^2|/|H^1|$?

Comment: Because $H^1,H^2$ of local fields tend to appear a lot in number theory and they’re not very explicit, so any piece of information is always welcome? I’m not in this domain – but that’s the reason why I wanted to learn its basics.

Comment: The denominator is $|H^1|$ not $|H^1|^2$? By any chance you remember the reference?

Comment: The denominator is indeed $|H^1|$, because It’s an Euler-Poincaré characteristic. I’m pretty sure that topic is explained in Neukirch’s *Cohomology of number fields*, but I don’t remember what my primary reference was.